# Opening up a new ViewController without passing in reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm very new to Xcode and have run into some difficulties when opening new views.

I currently use this way to open a new view. It is stored in a utilities NSObject class:

```
+ (void)OpenSettings:(UIViewController *)VC{
    Settings *settings = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    second.userID=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserID"] integerValue];
    [VC.self presentViewController:settingsInst animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Is there anyway that I can open a view WITHOUT having to pass in the current view controller? It's not of huge concern but to me makes it look a little untidy when having to call the following in the classes that want to open up my settings view:

```
[Utilities OpenSettings:self];
```

Comment: Create a category with your new method on the UIViewController class instead of making it some "global" class function of your "Utilities" class and you could just call `presentViewController` on `self` instead of `VC.self`. It all comes down to context.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Because you said that you are new to Xcode: do you know Storyboards? Please have a look at it if you haven't already: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html
As far as I understand, you are trying to encapsulate the "push settings view" functionality which could be very easy be made with segues in storyboards.

(2) If you do not want to use storyboards for whatever reason, you could write your own superclass that inherits from UIViewController:

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) openSettings
{
    Settings *settings = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    settings.userID=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserID"] integerValue];
    [self presentViewController:settings animated:NO completion:nil];
}   
@end
```

Any of your ViewController that inherit from MyViewController will now be able to use

```
[self openSettings]
```

Keep in mind, that UITableViewController is not a subcalls of UIViewController. If you want the same functionality here, you also have to create a custom MyTableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Exact solution depends on your view controller hierarchy. I'm assuming you have a `UINavigationController` on your active `window` (which are probably created in `AppDelegate`):

```
[self.navigationController.topViewController presentViewController:settings animated:NO completion:nil];
```

will do it. If you can post your main view structure, we can help more (Are you using a `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController` or just a view etc.?)